# Mails from deleted Outlook account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, user-accounts

All,

I accidentally deleted my Outlook account from Outlook 2007. I need to retrieve all the emails associated with the account, but cannot figure out how to do that.

Can anyone please let me know how to retrieve the emails from a deleted account?

Comment: You need to identify your Outlook configuration - whether you are downloading your emails or referring to them on a server.

Comment: I am downloading the emails.

Comment: Search your hard drive for any pst files. Deleting the Outlook profile shouldn't delete the pst files.